# Show error using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Using javascript i want to show error message, and the message will hide/disappear after 2 second . The error show perfectly and hide after 2 second but it does not work for the second time. if i reload my page it work perfectly again and so on.

JavaScript

```
if(task_hour == "hour" || task_minute == "minute"){

        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Add Time for the Task";
        setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("error").style.display="none"; }, 2000);

        return false;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="errordiv" align="center" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"> 
   <span id="error" style="color: red"> </span> 
</div>
```

Comment: What is the event triggering your code (like a button click) or is it loaded with the page itself?

Comment: How exactly do you show it? You should set `display: <smth>` to show it and `display: none` to hide.

Comment: How is your javascript being called...? is it in a function? or is this just running on page load?

Comment: Of course it won't work. After the first error, the element's style is `none`, and you never reset it to `block` to make it visible again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the div to be initially hidden (`display: none`) and use `display: block` to show it:

JS:

```
var timer = null;

function showError(message) {
    if (timer !== null) {
        // Clear previous timeout:
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = null;
    }
    var errorElement = document.getElementById("error");
    errorElement.innerHTML = message;
    errorElement.style.display = 'block';
    timer = setTimeout(function(){ errorElement.style.display = 'none'; }, 2000);
}

showError('Error!');
```

HTML:

```
<div id="errordiv" align="center" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"> 
    <span id="error" style="color: red; display: none"></span> 
</div>
```

Comment: what will happen if i add 1 error and 1 more after 1 second...?

Comment: Fair point. You could grab the handle for the existing setTimeout and cancel it if a new one is created. I think you'd probably use a global variable to hold it though, without any further context.

Comment: @KirillPisarev I've edited my answer to include this situation.

Comment: @AndrewDunai first it creates global variable that is bad practise, second, you may show only 1 message... [see](http://jsfiddle.net/7gsgvkwc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The second error appears in hiden div

you have to create a span, append it to wrapper with error text and after 2 seconds destroy it:

```
function showError(message){
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    var errorWrap = document.getElementById("error");

    span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
    errorWrap.appendChild(span);

    setTimeout(function(){ span.parentNode.removeChild(span); }, 2000);

    return false;
}

if(task_hour == "hour" || task_minute == "minute"){
    showError('Add Time for the Task');
}
```

[see](http://jsfiddle.net/7gsgvkwc/)

Comment: would you mind to provide a bit more informative answer?